# In Scala 2.8 collections, why was the Traversable type added above Iterable?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

I know that to be `Traversable`, you need only have a `foreach` method. `Iterable` requires an `iterator` method.

Both the Scala 2.8 collections SID and the "Fighting Bitrot with Types" paper are basically silent on the subject of why `Traversable` was added. The SID only says "David McIver... proposed Traversable as a generalization of Iterable."

I have vaguely gathered from discussions on IRC that it has to do with reclaiming resources when traversal of a collection terminates?

The following is probably related to my question.  There are some odd-looking function definitions in `TraversableLike.scala`, for example:

```
def isEmpty: Boolean = {
  var result = true
  breakable {
    for (x <- this) {
      result = false
      break
    }
  }
  result
}
```

I assume there's a good reason that wasn't just written as:

```
def isEmpty: Boolean = {
  for (x <- this)
    return false
  true
}
```

Comment: `Traversable` is motivated in Ch. 24 of Programming in Scala, 2nd ed.; in some cases it is easier to implement efficiently `foreach` than `iterator`.

Comment: Regarding last question: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5101

Answer (score 11):

I asked David McIver about this on IRC.  He said he no longer remembered all of the reasons, but they included:

- "iterators are often annoying... to implement"
- iterators are "sometimes unsafe (due to setup/teardown at the beginning and end of the loop)"
- Hoped-for efficiency gains from implementing some things via foreach rather than via iterators (gains not necessarily yet actually demonstrated with the current HotSpot compiler)

Comment: Note that in the Scala 2.13 collections rewrite, we got rid of `Traversable` again and went back to an iterator-based design.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect one reason is that it's a lot easier to write a concrete implementation for a collection with an abstract `foreach` method than for one with an abstract `iterator` method.  For example, in C# you can write the implementation the `GetEnumerator` method of `IEnumerable<T>` as if it were a `foreach` method:

```
IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() 
{
    yield return t1;
    yield return t2;
    yield return t3;
}
```

(The compiler generates an appropriate state machine to drive the iteration through the `IEnumerator`.)  In Scala, you would have to write your own implementation of `Iterator[T]` to do this.  For `Traversable`, you can do the equivalent of the above implementation:

```
def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit = {
  f(t1); f(t2); f(t3)
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to scala, but since you don't actually return anything, couldn't you just write `def foreach[U](f: A => U){f(t1); f(t2); f(t3) }` ?

Comment: `foreach` states that it returns `Unit` and so discards the result of the body block `f(t3)` of type `U`.

Answer (score -3):

just regarding your last question:

```
def isEmpty: Boolean = {
  for (x <- this)
    return false
  true
}
```

This gets roughly translated by the compiler to:

```
def isEmpty: Boolean = {
  this.foreach(x => return false)
  true
}
```

So you are simply not able to break out of foreach, isEmpty will always return true.

This is why "hacky" Breakable was constructed which breaks out of foreach by throwing a Control-Exception, catching it in `breakable` and returns.

Comment: Actually you are wrong about return in scala.
Scala does support Non-Local Returns.

Comment: Uh, this is astonishing, you're right. Has this always been valid??