# Scala: What is the difference between Traversable and Iterable traits in Scala collections?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602379/in-scala-2-8-collections-why-was-the-traversable-type-added-above-iterable) but still don't understand the difference between Iterable and Traversable traits. Can someone explain ?

Comment: There is no more `Traversable` in [Scala 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0) (it is still kept as a deprecated alias for `Iterable` until 2.14)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

To put it simply, iterators keep state, traversables don't.

A `Traversable` has one abstract method: `foreach`. When you call `foreach`, *the collection* will feed the passed function all the elements it keeps, one after the other.

On the other hand, an `Iterable` has as abstract method `iterator`, which returns an `Iterator`. You can call `next` on an `Iterator` to get the next element at the time of your choosing. Until you do, it has to keep track of where it was in the collection, and what's next.

Comment: But `Iterable` extends `Traversable`, so I guess you mean `Traversable`s that are not `Iterable`s.

Comment: @RobinGreen I mean complying with the `Traversable` interface does not require keeping state, while complying with `Iterator` interface does.

Comment: `Traversable`s that are `Iterable` do not keep any iteration state. It's the `Iterator` created and returned by the `Iterable` that keeps the state.

Comment: Is is worth to note that as of 2.13 trait Traversable is deprecated. To quote Stefan Zeiger, "The Traversable abstraction has not carried its weight in the current library and will likely not resurface in the new design. Everything we want to do can be expressed with Iterable."

Answer (score 237):

Think of it as the difference between blowing and sucking.

When you have call a `Traversable`s `foreach`, or its derived methods, it will blow its values into your function one at a time - so it has control over the iteration.

With the `Iterator` returned by an `Iterable` though, you suck the values out of it, controlling when to move to the next one yourself.

Comment: People use to call this _pushing_ and _pulling_ instead of _blowing_ and _sucking_, but I like your open-mindedness.

Comment: Never forgetting this when asked in my next interview

Answer (score 27):

**tl;dr** `Iterables` are `Traversables` that can produce stateful `Iterators`

---

First, know that `Iterable` is subtrait of `Traversable`.

Second,

- `Traversable` requires implementing the `foreach` method, which is used by everything else.
- `Iterable` requires implementing the `iterator` method, which is used by everything else.

For example, the implemetation of `find` for `Traversable` uses `foreach` (via a for comprehension) and throws a `BreakControl` exception to halt iteration once a satisfactory element has been found.

```
trait TravserableLike {
  def find(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
    var result: Option[A] = None
    breakable {
      for (x <- this)
        if (p(x)) { result = Some(x); break }
    }
    result
  }
}
```

In contrast, the `Iterable` subtract overrides this implementation and calls `find` on the `Iterator`, which simply stops iterating once the element is found:

```
trait Iterable {
  override /*TraversableLike*/ def find(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] =
    iterator.find(p)
}

trait Iterator {
  def find(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
    var res: Option[A] = None
      while (res.isEmpty && hasNext) {
        val e = next()
        if (p(e)) res = Some(e)
      }
    res
  }
}
```

It'd be nice not to throw exceptions for `Traversable` iteration, but that's the only way to partially iterate when using just `foreach`.

From one perspective, `Iterable` is the more demanding/powerful trait, as you can easily implement `foreach` using `iterator`, but you can't really implement `iterator` using `foreach`.

---

In summary, `Iterable` provides a way to pause, resume, or stop iteration via a stateful `Iterator`. With `Traversable`, it's all or nothing (sans exceptions for flow control).

Most of the time it doesn't matter, and you'll want the more general interface. But if you ever need more customized control over iteration, you'll need an `Iterator`, which you can retrieve from an `Iterable`.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer sounds good. Let me see if I can to put it in my own words.

So an Iterable can give you an iterator, that lets you traverse the elements one at a time (using next()), and stop and go as you please. To do that the iterator needs to keep an internal "pointer" to the element's position. But a Traversable gives you the method, foreach, to traverse all elements at once without stopping.

Something like Range(1, 10) needs to have only 2 integers as state as a Traversable. But Range(1, 10) as an Iterable gives you an iterator which needs to use 3 integers for state, one of which is an index.

Considering that Traversable also offers foldLeft, foldRight, its foreach needs to traverse the elements in a known and fixed order. Therefore it's possible to implement an iterator for a Traversable. E.g.
    def iterator = toList.iterator