# Difference between Traversable , gentraversable and iterable trait

Tags: scala

I read many answers but still can't understand it .So Can some please explain me difference between iterable , Traversable and genTraversable ?

Comment: Did you read the scaladoc for those traits? Also, why do you need to know? Are you implementing a collection class that needs to make this distinction?

Comment: Actually sir I have an assignment where I need to explain it's difference . so sir I'm asking for explanation ..

Comment: And what did you get from reading the scaladoc and the code?

Comment: Pushing and pulling transverable and iyerable

Comment: Another way you could learn the difference is by creating a class that implements those traits and see what the differences are.

Comment: Can u plss explain 

Comment: You have homework to do. You asked the stackoverflow community to do your homework for you. I just told you that you have to do an amount of work, and we should be able to help you when you get stuck. So, it all starts with you doing some work and showing it to us.

Comment: Ohkk sir , Ty !!!

Comment: partial duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425370/scala-what-is-the-difference-between-traversable-and-iterable-traits-in-scala-c